# NUnit and NMock- ExpectAndReturn - How to tell NMock to expect CreateObjectSet<T>

Tags: unit-testing, generics, nunit, nmock

I have the following

```
var objSet = new DynamicMock(typeof(IObjectSet<Nationality>));
objSet.ExpectAndReturn("GetAll", new List<Nationality>
{
 new Nationality 
 {
    //obj init here
 },
 new Nationality 
 {
    //obj init here
 }
}.AsQueryable());
```

which works just fine (I can call blah.GetAll() and I get the expected list back).

What I'd like to do (if possible?) is tell another DynamicMock to expect a method with the following signature

```
obj.CreateObjectSet<RandomCustomType>()
```

But I am unsure of how to include/configure the call to expect the '`<Type>`'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure [NMock 1.x](http://www.nmock.org/nmock1-documentation.html) doesn't support Generic methods, and it's no longer supported. What about moving to another mocking framework other than NMock, which has typed interface, and not based on hardcoded strings?
In Rhino Mocks (for example) you could do this as follows (example taken from [yet another StackObverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678487/how-do-you-assert-a-generic-method-was-called-with-rhino-mocks)):

```
  var fakeSession = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ISession>();
  fakeSession.Expect(s => s.Query<SomeClass>());
```

Comment: I rather feared that might be the best advice - this is part of an old project at work, partially covered by unit tests using NUnit. Think I might just refactor them to use Rhino Mocks. Have tried this issue with RhinoMocks using method you suggested and sorted the problem - thanks!